# Regular Expression Assistance (RegEx)

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string

I'm trying to create a regular expression string that will capture the data between the opening and closing [] brackets and include the brackets from the following data:

```
data: [{"LOTS OF DATA}],
  datatype: "local",
```

So far I'm using a regEx string "data:(.*)" and this is returning:

```
[{"LOTS OF DATA}],
```

This is almost correct but includes the ',' and the reason this is working is because theres a newline or carriage return before 'datatype:' So I have two questions:

1. How do I capture all characters including the newline & carriage return?
2. How do I match the ',   datatype:' string. The issue with this is that I cannot guarantee the character type and number of characters between the ','  and 'datatype:' string, I need a wild card? The regEx string would look something like "data:(.*),???datatype:" where ??? is the wildcard?

Thanks for your help, this will be used within an iOS application.

Comment: There is no need for regular expressions. Use simple, basic substrings.

Comment: ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Comment: I'm not sure from your example, but if you are parsing JSON, use a JSON parser. And without a better idea of how the input string can be, it's impossible to write a good regex that doesn't randomly break on some valid input.

Answer (score 0):

```
data:\s*\[([^\[\]]*)\]\s*,\s*datatype:
```

This implies that no square brackets may occur within LOTS OF DATA.
You could even spare the trailing 'datatype:' match.

Should LOTS OF DATA contains square brackets you would have to come up with a more precise specification of its content.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the following string appears to be whats needed:

     data:(.*),\s*datatype:

Comment: Thanks for your help and the following string appears to be whats needed:

     data:(.*),\s*datatype:

To answer a couple of questions, the data between the [] brackets is a valid JSON string and the reason why I'm trying to extract it, but it's contained within a HTML page so substrings not a real option. Once I have the string I'm using a JSON parser to process the data and thats why its important to have the [] at each so that it's valid. The example provided didn't capture the trailing ] resulting in invalid JSON but was still helpful.

Comment: Duncan, .* will not catch newlines. JSON will not prevent line breaks to occur between the [ ] brackets. It might even happen that [ or ] will occur within a string literal which screws even my proposal. Unless you have precise control over what input you get, you should be very careful when choosing your regular expression. You definitely don't want your code to croak at the customer. Maybe it's better to revert the HTML markup and feed the whole text into a JSON parser. Just my $0.02.